# How to incorporate a javafx GUI create by fxml with a javafx gui created by hardcode?

Tags: java, javafx

Is it poosible to create a button on the javafx fxml using screen builder such that the button would run an javafx file where its GUI was created via coding.

**FXML**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        pane.getChildren().setAll(heatMap.getHeatMapImage());
        heatMap.addEvents(events);
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    // BasicConfigurator.configure();

    launch(args);
}
```

**JAVAFX GUI CREATED BY CODE**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    pane.getChildren().setAll(heatMap.getHeatMapImage());
    HBox hbox = new HBox(pane); 

    // set spacing 
    hbox.setSpacing(10); 
    // set alignment for the HBox 
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 

    // create a scene 
    Scene Overlay = new Scene(hbox, 1000, 600); 
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\map.jpeg");
    Image image = new Image(input);
    BackgroundImage backgroundimage = new BackgroundImage(image,  
                                        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,  
                                        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,  
                                        BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,  
                                           BackgroundSize.DEFAULT); 
    Background background = new Background(backgroundimage);
    hbox.setBackground(background);

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX HeatMap Demo");
    stage.setScene(Overlay);
    stage.show();
    heatMap.addEvents(events);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dimension2D mapDimension = new Dimension2D(1500, 1577);
    Point2D     upperLeft    = new Point2D(0, 9.8);
    Point2D     lowerRight   = new Point2D(53.45, 10.2);
    Point2D     location     = new Point2D(53.7, 9.95);

    //System.out.println(Helper.latLongToPixel(mapDimension, upperLeft, lowerRight, location));

    launch(args);
}
```

So my question would be how do I call my JAVAFX GUI created by code from the fxml file ?

Comment: An class extending `Application` is the wrong place to put logic like this. Only a single `Application` instance is launched and any other instances of `Application` subtypes are just unnecessarily big objects that may not have been completely initialized. But what prevents you from moving the logic in the one `Application` class to one of the event handler methods of your controller class???

Comment: So the JAVAFX gui that was created via coding was actually a heatmap that I followed from a guide. So I am not sure how to incorporate my own heatmap that runs it own application into another compile GUI application that was create via scene builder (fxml)

Comment: To me, it looks like you went [here](https://github.com/HanSolo/FxHeatMap) and looked at the [demo code](https://github.com/HanSolo/FxHeatMap/blob/master/src/eu/hansolo/fx/heatmap/Demo.java) and you don't know how to incorporate [`FxHeatMap`](https://github.com/HanSolo/FxHeatMap/tree/master/src/eu/hansolo/fx/heatmap) into your current project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the GUI in an `fxml` file and specify its controller:

GUI2.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fx_tests.GUI2Controller" />
```

Do the initialization in the controller.
Add getters for information that you want to retrieve from the controller later:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class GUI2Controller{

    @FXML StackPane root;
    private Point2D[] events;
    private SimpleHeatMap heatMap;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        //initialize here all info that you want to retrieve later
        heatMap = new SimpleHeatMap(400, 400, ColorMapping.LIME_YELLOW_RED, 40);
        events  = new Point2D[] {
                new Point2D(110, 238),
                new Point2D(120, 144),
                new Point2D(207, 119),
                new Point2D(315, 348),
                new Point2D(264, 226),
                new Point2D(280, 159),
                new Point2D(240, 186),
                new Point2D(228, 170),
                new Point2D(234, 160),
                new Point2D(214, 170),
                new Point2D(200, 200),
        };

        //you could also populate root
        //root.getChildren().setAll(heatMap.getHeatMapImage());
    }

    public SimpleHeatMap getHeatMap() {
        return heatMap;
    }

    public  Point2D[] getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
}
```

Use it in the application:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxmlTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GUI2.fxml"));
            Pane root = fxmlLoader.load();
            GUI2Controller controller = fxmlLoader.getController(); 

            //retrieve info from controller 
            SimpleHeatMap heatMap = controller.getHeatMap();
            Point2D[] events = controller.getEvents();

            //todo: use as needed 
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }
}
```